# Returning a nested class from a method

Tags: scala

There is an error I don't understand:

```
class MyClass1 {
  private class MyClass1Internal(a: Int, b: Int, c: String, d: String)
  def method1 = {
    // doing something
    new MyClass1Internal(1, 2, "3", "4")
  }
}
```

an error

```
private class MyClass1Internal escapes its defining scope as part of type MyClass1.this.MyClass1Internal
[error]   def method1 = {
[error]       ^
```

What is it about and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MyClass1Internal` is private and thus should never be able to be accessed outside of `MyClass1`, but `method` will return an instance of it outside this class (as it's public), thus breaking its defining scope.

I bet if you defined `method` as private it would fix this error.  You could also make the nested class not be private.

One more thing, if you wanted other code be able to work with that class but not be able to instantiate it, then just make the constructor private and the class public like so:

```
class MyClass1 {
  class MyClass1Internal private[MyClass1](a: Int, b: Int, c: String, d: String)
  def method1 = {
    // doing something
    new MyClass1Internal(1, 2, "3", "4")
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't make it private, I need it to be public.

Comment: Well then you can't do what you are trying to do. That inner class is private. It should never be accessible outside of the containing class. You could also make the internal class not be private. Not sure if you can do that either though

Comment: Can I ask why you want this class to be private. Maybe there is a better solution if I can better understand the problem

Comment: I want to return this class as a result type instead of returning just a Tuple, this class will actually have about 10 fields in it. so returning a `Tuple10[....]` is not so reasonable.

Comment: Then you can't make `MyClass1Internal` private.

Answer (score 1):

The public API of `MyClass1` uses a part of its private API (`MyClass1Internal`). This is bad, as another class does not know `MyClass1Internal` and hence cannot make sense of the return type of `method1`.

If you do not want to expose `MyClass1Internal` but still return an instance to it, you'll have to upcast `method1`'s return type to something public. For example:

```
trait MyClass1Interface {
  def a: Int
}

class MyClass1 {
  private class MyClass1Internal(val a: Int, b: Int, c: String, d: String)
    extends MyClass1Interface
  def method1: MyClass1Interface = {
    // doing something
    new MyClass1Internal(1, 2, "3", "4")
  }
}
```

This allows you to hide the exact implementation of the interface in your class, but keep the method public. (Your interface can of course still be part of the class if you prefer that).